# Subclass ActsAsTaggableOn:Tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia, acts-as-taggable-on

Trying to subclass `ActsAsTaggableOn:Tag` to index tags when creating.

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    include AlgoliaSearch

    TAG_INDEX = "Tags_#{Rails.env}"

    algoliasearch per_environment: true do
      attribute :name, :taggings_count
      attributesToIndex ['name']
      customRanking ['desc(taggings_count)']
    end
  end
end
```

**What I'm trying to do:**
When a tag is created, index it in Algolia.

**What is happening:**
When saving a tag, or a model that uses `acts_as_taggable_on` (e.g. Post), I'm getting this error:

`undefined method find_or_create_all_with_like_by_name`

It appears that the `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` subclass is not able to find the parents `find_or_create_all_with_like_by_name` method.

Anyone know if there is a way to subclass the Tag class?

Answer (score 0):

I would question if you really want to subclass it at all when you can just create a module and use it to decorate the existing class with this new feature.

```
module MyTagDecorator
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include AlgoliaSearch
      TAG_INDEX = "Tags_#{Rails.env}"
      algoliasearch per_environment: true do
        attribute :name, :taggings_count
        attributesToIndex ['name']
        customRanking ['desc(taggings_count)']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then include the module in the class you are extending:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.include(MyTagDecorator)
```

See:

- [Justin Weiss: 3 Ways To Monkeypatch Without Making a Mess](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)